# Is it memory safe to ignore the [NSTimer scheduled...] method's return value in ARC?

Tags: memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, nstimer

I just want to make a simple oeration after several seconds for only once. I wrote this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledWimerWithTimeInterval:seconds 
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(someMethod:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];
```

And took no concern of the return value.

Was that OK? Would the ignored NSTimer object been released and de-allocated after the `someMethod:` had finished operating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [References to Timers and Object Lifetimes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000807-SW6) in "Timer Programming Topics":

> Because the run loop maintains the timer, from the perspective of
>   object lifetimes there’s typically no need to keep a reference to a
>   timer *after you’ve scheduled it*. ...

The first code example in ["Scheduled Timers"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000807-SW2) is almost
identical to yours, and also ignores the return value.

Comment: Thank you! The ways I used NSTimer are so simple that I have not read the document yet...